# How to list all versions of an npm module?

Tags: node.js, npm

In order to see all the versions of a node module [webpack], I have executed below command in windows command prompt

```
npm view webpack versions
```

This command only displays first 100 versions and later displays "331 more" text.

How will I be able to list all versions?

Comment: See here for listing all `node modules`.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981938/print-a-list-of-all-installed-node-js-modules

Comment: This `npm ls --depth=0` will list all local modules as `name@version`. `

Comment: Or globals: `npm -g ls --depth=0`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm view get more items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40565331/npm-view-get-more-items)

Answer (score 621, accepted):

Usually I do this if I want to see all versions

```
npm view webpack versions --json
```

Comment: Leaving off the `--json` flag formats it a bit nicer on my machine.

Comment: @Niek.. depends .. do you want incomplete for long lists, or json which gives you all.

Comment: this lists versions in their natural (numerical) order

Comment: If you want to view the release date of each version, check the "Versions" tab of the package on npmjs.com. For example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte?activeTab=versions

Answer (score 57):

NEW:

You now need to ask for `versions` instead of `version`

```
npm show webpack@* versions
```

OLD:

This won't list alpha or beta releases

```
npm show webpack@* version
```

Comment: what is the difference between `npm show` `npm view` and `npm info` ?

Comment: @AkinHwan Nothing. They are all aliases of the same thing

Comment: Yeah but requires shell-escaping. It should have been instead: `npm show 'webpack@*' version`

Comment: This prints versions indefinitely, even alpha versions, not sure why but maybe it's that wildcard.

Comment: this lists versions in the order in which they are listed on npm e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack?activeTab=versions

Answer (score 25):

with yarn its just `yarn info react-dnd versions`, you can leave versions off for a lot of other info

Comment: There is even a better way, if you type `yarn add <package>@adfadf` yarn will prompt you with all the versions you can install from, you're welcome

Answer (score 9):

you can view the available versions of any package using `npm show <package_name> versions`

for webpack use `npm show webpack versions`

Answer (score 2):

In the root of the package/module run:

```
npm view . versions
```