# Dumping whole array: console.log and console.dir output "... NUM more items]"

Tags: arrays, node.js, v8, dump, console.log

I am trying to log a long array so I can copy it quickly in my terminal. However, if I try and log the array it looks like:

```
['item',
 'item',
  >>more items<<<
  ... 399 more items ]
```

How can I log the entire array so I can copy it really quickly?

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 1));`.

Comment: So, why not just create your own loop and output it exactly the way you want one at a time?  You are in complete control of the output when you do it that way.

Comment: If I can I would advice changing the marked answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41669062/124486 as it's a much better solution if you're on Node v10+

Comment: @SebastianSimon, that kills the highlighting.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

## Setting `maxArrayLength`

There are a few methods all of which require setting `maxArrayLength` which otherwise defaults to 100.

1. Provide the override as an option to `console.dir`

   ```
   console.dir(myArry, {'maxArrayLength': null});
   ```
2. Set [`util.inspect.defaultOptions.maxArrayLength = null;`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_defaultoptions) which will impact all calls to `console.log` and `util.format`
3. Call `util.inspect` yourself with [options](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options).

   ```
   const util = require('util')
   console.log(util.inspect(array, { maxArrayLength: null }))
   ```

Comment: Specifically I like also to do `console.log(util.inspect(arrayofObjects, {maxArrayLength: null, depth:null }))` to go deep into objects as well.

Comment: Just had a chance to check this, saving as the proper answer

Comment: @MichaelHellein passing `maxArrayLength` as an option to console.log just ends up printing it as well. `... 267 more items ] { maxArrayLength: 500 }`. I had to use `console.dir` instead of `console.log` in order to get it to work.

Comment: Just a note for posterity: the answer that I gave has been so significantly edited, I don't think it's fair call it mine anymore. I would have preferred that such a substantial edit were provided as a separate answer.

Comment: @MichaelHellein, you’re absolutely right. The original answer didn’t suggest `console.dir` or setting the global defaults, _at all_. Such an aggressive edit shouldn’t be made.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you're here because you want to print _everything_, you will also want to set `maxStringLength` to `null`, or you'll have the same `...` problem with long strings.

Answer (score 52):

Michael Hellein's answer didn't work for me, but a close version did:

```
console.dir(myArray, {'maxArrayLength': null})
```

This was the only solution that worked for me as `JSON.stringify()` was too ugly for my needs and I didn't need to write the code to print it out one at a time.

Comment: same here, the other option would print the same thing

Answer (score 23):

## [Using `console.table`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_table_tabulardata_properties)

Available in Node v10+, [and all modern web-browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table), you can use `console.table()` instead, which will output a beautiful utf8 table where each row represents an element of the array.

```
> console.table([{ a: 1, b: 'Y' }, { a: 'Z', b: 2 }], ['a']);

┌─────────┬─────┐
│ (index) │  a  │
├─────────┼─────┤
│    0    │  1  │
│    1    │ 'Z' │
└─────────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Here is the support.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table

Comment: Don't want a different package sorry, hoping to do this with native node

Comment: @Antoine it's now in Node v10 you may consider reassessing the question. This is a better method =)

Comment: `console.table` function is pretty useful, but the OP asked for a function that prints out and allow them to copy the output quickly; supposedly still in JS format (to paste somewhere else or to cache the result). Hence `console.dir()` from the top answer satisfies better the question.

Answer (score 10):

Just found that option `maxArrayLength` works well with `console.dir` too:

`console.dir(array, {depth: null, colors: true, maxArrayLength: null});`

Answer (score 9):

What's wrong with `myArray.forEach(item => console.log(item))`?

Comment: I want to add these items to an existing array.

Comment: if you want to add one array to another, why not use [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)?

Comment: I think he may want to existing structure, rather than item by item. It also is a problem when each item is an array which is "too long"