# the content is too long, How to display the complete content in console.log()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a big array, it has many element,
I need to display it in console,
I use `console.log()` but only a part of it was displayed.

How to display full content?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run it through `JSON.stringify` so you are logging a single string and not a complex data structure.

Comment: Why does this happen though with a complex data structure?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
 console.dir(myArry, {'maxArrayLength': null});
```

The console method log() displays the toString representation of any object passed to it. The Console method dir() displays an interactive list of the properties of the specified JavaScript object

Link for reference :  [Dumping whole array: console.log and console.dir output "... NUM more items]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41669039/dumping-whole-array-console-log-and-console-dir-output-num-more-items)

Answer (score 1):

as say here [How can I get the full object in Node.js's console.log(), rather than '[Object]'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-jss-console-log-rather-than-object)

you can convert your element (object or array) directly in json by using

```js
console.log('my elem : %j', myObject);
```

or if you want more display option, you can use util.inspect

```
const util = require('util')
console.log(util.inspect(myObject, {showHidden: false, depth: null, colors: true}))
```

Answer (score 0):

For larger arrays, this works nicely:

```
myLargeArray.forEach( element => console.log( JSON.stringify( element ) ) );
```